# Ansible playbook delete multiple/single files based on date condition

Tags: ansible

I have a few files in the following format

```
test_war.war.1.backup20200101
test_war.war.2.backup20200101
test_war.war.2.backup20200102
test_war.war.3.backup20200103
test_war.war.4.backup20200103
test_war.war.5.backup20200103
test_war.war.3.backup20200104
test_war.war.4.backup20200105
test_war.war.2.backup20200106
test_war.war.1.backup20200107
test1_war.war.1.backup20200101
test1_war.war.2.backup20200101
test1_war.war.2.backup20200102
test1_war.war.3.backup20200103
test1_war.war.4.backup20200103
test1_war.war.5.backup20200103
test1_war.war.3.backup20200104
test1_war.war.4.backup20200105
test1_war.war.2.backup20200106
test1_war.war.1.backup20200107
```

I would like to delete files if the files is less than 20 days from from the current date. So it the current date is 20200125, all the below files should be deleted

```
test_war.war.1.backup20200101
test_war.war.2.backup20200101
test_war.war.2.backup20200102
test_war.war.3.backup20200103
test_war.war.4.backup20200103
test_war.war.5.backup20200103
test_war.war.3.backup20200104
test_war.war.4.backup20200105
test1_war.war.1.backup20200101
test1_war.war.2.backup20200101
test1_war.war.2.backup20200102
test1_war.war.3.backup20200103
test1_war.war.4.backup20200103
test1_war.war.5.backup20200103
test1_war.war.3.backup20200104
test1_war.war.4.backup20200105
```

I have done some coding from my part. Would like to know is this approach correct or are there any better approach

```
- name: Find war files
  find:
    paths: "{{ folder_war }}"
    patterns:
      - 'test_war.war.*.bakup*'
      - 'test1_war.war.*.bakup*'
    age: 20d
    recurse: yes
  register: removeFiles

- name: Remove war files
  file:
    path: "{{item.path}}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{removeFiles.files}}"
```

Comment: I would have done the same way you did. You will need `find` module to find list of files using certain conditions.

Comment: thanks for clarifications